# Average number of pairs of distinct adjacent balls in a circle fashion？

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given m red balls and n blue balls arranged randomly in a circle fashion, what is the average number of pairs of distinct adjacent balls?

For example, given 3 red balls and 2 blue balls arranged randomly in a circle fashion, there are two kinds of arrangement, **RBRRB** and **RRRBB**:

the circle **RBRRB** would contribute 4 pairs,**RB** in slot (1,2)**BR** in slot (2,3), **RB** in slot (4,5) and **BR** in slot (5,1);

the circle **RRRBB** would contribute 2 pairs, **RB** in slot (3,4) and **BR** in slot (5,1)

Then，the average number of pairs of distinct adjacent balls is (4+2)/2=3.

Comment: Hint: You only have to calculated the probability that, given two random balls, they are different, and then multiply by $m+n.$

Comment: See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/),
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not 
independent of each other.